# Django | Mostar lista en template no muestra contenido

Tags: django, django-views

Al tratar de hacer una prueba de mostrar contenido de data en el template no muestra nada más que el texto plano. ¿Qué puede estar mal?
Gracias.

**Urls.py**

```
path('hacertest/',
        views.test_list,
        name='test-hacertest',
    ),
```

**Views.py**

```
def test_list(request):
    data = {
        'title':'Los 50 mejores test',
        'categoría':'Categoría1'
    }
    return render(request,'prueba.html',data)
```

**prueba.html**

```
 Prueba de imprimir datos
    
    {% for data in data %}
    
        {{ data.title }}
    
    {% endfor %}
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `prueba.html` no tiene ninguna etiqueta html, ni en el código que muestras parece heredar de otra plantilla. Para mostrar html tendrás que tener una plantilla que contenga la maquetación html y marcar tus variables (p.e. `<p>{{ data.title }}</p>`)

Comment: Para ver datos creo que no es necesario maquetar html. Se muestra la información como texto plano. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Efectivamente, no es necesario, pero en la pregunta pone «no muestra más que texto plano» y por tanto da lugar a pensar que quizás estabas queriendo mostrar html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edito*:

Haré un ejemplo con el siguiente path: `localhost/test/`:

- Añado en el fichero `urls.py` la ruta en la que quiero imprimir el diccionario de prueba:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        route='test/', view=views.test_dictionary, name='Print dictionary in a loop.'  
    ),
]
```

- Añado en el fichero `views.py` el método o función `test_dictionary` (dependiendo de si trabajas con clases o no) que hemos definido en el fichero anterior cuando haga match la petición con la ruta `test/`. Los datos que envíamos, los insertamos en un diccionario:

```
def test_dictionary(request):
    data = {
        'title':'Los 50 mejores test',
        'categoría':'Categoría1'
    }
    return render(request,'prueba.html', {'datos' : data})
```

- Veo que en este caso has usado la función `render` para renderizar la plantilla. Entiendo que has importado previamente el módulo correspondiente para hacerlo: `from django.shortcuts import render` *

- Creamos en la carpeta del proyecto, dentro de la carpeta `templates`, el fichero `prueba.html` y en el insertamos el siguiente contenido:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Django render example</title>
</head>
<body>

{% for key, value in datos.items %}
    <h1> Key del diccionario: {{ key }} </h1>
    <p> Value del diccionario: {{ value }} </p>
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

De esta manera, podemos acceder a los `items` del diccionario e imprimir c/u de sus valores, key y value:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En caso de no enviar un diccionario, que sería el ejemplo que proporcionas:

```
# Ejemplo del render:
return render(request,'prueba.html', data)
```

Puedes imprimir todo lo que existe en una `template` de Django, es decir, todas las variables a las que podrías acceder por así decirlo, utilizando [debug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#debug) en tu template:

```
{% debug %}
```

Verás que entre todo el contenido (e.g variables predefinidas por el framework), existe el diccionario que has enviado desde tu controlador. En este caso la forma de acceder al diccionario al enviarlo de esta manera es la siguiente:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Django render example</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1> Título: {{ title }} </h1>
<h1> Otro título: {{ categoria }}

</body>
</html>
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias Adrián, pero una pregunta. No haces referencia a la plantilla en ningún momento. ¿Cómo llega a la plantilla ese resultado? Un saludo.

Comment: Perdona, no había entendido la pregunta. He hecho un pequeño ejemplo aprovechando un app en Django que he estado construyendo. Espero ser de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tan completa respuesta Adrián. Una pregunta. En el caso de querer recuperar en un def por POST los valores que el usuario a introducido o respondiendo. ¿Cómo recuperas esos valores en un def de la view? Gracias.